# Barracuda Cuda Drive on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, cloud, copy.com

I recently switched from DropBox to [Copy](https://www.copy.com) because of its great Linux integration. Now I have seen that they also Provide software for Windows and OSX which lets you access files in the cloud without having to sync them to your local device (so it basically mounts your cloud drive), which really makes sense having a small laptop with only a few hundred GBs of storage space.

The software itself ([Cuda Drive](https://www.barracuda.com/products/cudadrive)) is not available for any Linux distribution (yet?), but there might be a way to map your copy cloud as a "network drive" using any Linux distro?

Anybody has tried something like that and/or has an idea of how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

I too switched from DropBox to Copy because of its great Linux integration. 
I have tried their software CudaDrive on Windows which lets you access files in the cloud without having to sync them to your local device.

I achieved what you are trying to do on Suse and *ubuntus 15.04 and 15.10 by using third party software called StorageMadeEasy. You may not wish to use a third party proprietary piece of software and certainly askubuntu mods dislike this solution but it meets every criteria in your question.

*They provide a deb which once installed allows you to map your copy cloud as a network drive.*

Steps:

- Create a free account with StorageMadeEasy and link your copy account
  to it.
- Download and install the deb (or relevant package for other distros)
  from https://storagemadeeasy.com/LinuxDrive/
- Create an empty folder that you can mount the copy folder to Search
  SME from the menu, this will bring up three options, choose SME
  client.
- Sign in with your StorageMadeEasy account
- Select the previously created empty folder
- Click the big Mount button and wait for the success popup.
- You can now browse and edit your copy.com files as if they were
  local.

Alternatively with the StorageMadeEasy account you can access the copy.com folder using WebDAV. I'm afraid I haven't experience with this but this option is applicable to every linux distro whether a package exists or not.

I'm not associated with SME or Barracuda in any way other than being a customer.

Comment: We dislike this solution? O_o

Comment: Worded differently this answer was removed. I took that as a sign of dislike.